# Expresion regular funciona en web pero no en SQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Tengo esta expresion regular con los ejemplos que le corresponden:
https://regex101.com/r/TaNU5l/1, cuando pongo la misma sentencia para hacer una busqueda SQL me da error.

He intentado usar la expresión LIKE y la REGEXP, estoy usando SQL manager 2007 para MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabla
WHERE campo REGEXP '^7\d*$';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de `MySQL 8.0.4`, MySQL usaba la implementación de expresiones regulares de Henry Spencer, por lo que expresiones como `\d` no eran soportadas. En su lugar había que usar `[0-9]` o `[:digit:]`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo REGEXP '^7[0-9]*$'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HsMtJ4ZZkC12GzXsd7d52/3)</kbd>

---

A partir de `MySQL v8.0.4`, MySQL implementa el soporte de expresiones regulares utilizando International Components for Unicode (ICU) y expresiones como `\d`, `\D`, etc. ya son soportadas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo REGEXP '^7\\d*$'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HsMtJ4ZZkC12GzXsd7d52/2)</kbd>

**Referencias:**

- [Regular Expression Compatibility Considerations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility)
- [ICU - Regular Expression Metacharacters](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Regular-Expression-Metacharacters)

Comment: Te invito que lo pruebes en la pagina del consorcio, veras como si funciona.

Comment: @Srsole se refiere a MySQL, no a la pagina. Lo probe y efectivamente no soporta la expresion `\d`

Comment: efectivamente, en la web del consorcio funciona, pero en SQL Manager me dice que me pire. Estas en lo correcto.

Comment: Desde la versión 8.0.4, MySQL implementa el soporte a [12.8.2 Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) por medio de la librería [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), en la documentación de dicha librería mencionan el soporte al metacarácter `\b` así como al metacarácter `\d`, así que una expresión regular como: `/\b7\d*\b/` debería poder ser usada en MySQL, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e35fa56b90617aa039f65f056016a9ad).

Comment: @wchiquito, muchas gracias por el comentario. He actualizado mi respuesta.